# C# Create zip, add file but can't open

Tags: c#, zip

I'm not a C# developer so my knowledge is limited. However, I'm trying to write a program in C# which exports the Windows security log for certain date and export it as an evtx file.

But then what I have to do is add this evtx file to a zip file. The code below creates the zip file (I can see it) and adds evtx file to the zip (I think because in windows explore the size changes from 0kb to more).

```
#region "COMPRESS THE EVTX FILE INTO A ZIP FILE: "
// First create a new ZIP archive in the "Achives" folder.
string zipFileName = "Zip-" + getDateTimeStamp(1) + ".zip";
string zipFilePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(zipEvtxDirectoryPath, zipFileName);
ZipArchive zipFile = ZipFile.Open(zipFilePath, ZipArchiveMode.Create);

// Add the evtx file created in program directory to this zip archive.
Console.WriteLine(evtxFilePath);
Console.WriteLine(evtxFileName);
zipFile.CreateEntryFromFile(evtxFilePath, evtxFileName);

//evtxFilePath = "D:\TEST\VS\FilesAndFolders\TestDirectory\Archives\Security-Log-Archive-11-01-2015-04-18-58.evtx"
//evtxFileName = "Security-Log-Archive-11-01-2015-04-18-58.evtx"
//zipFilePath = "D:\TEST\VS\FilesAndFolders\TestDirectory\Archives\Zip-11-01-2015-04-18-58"

#endregion
```

But when I go try to open the zip file using windows explorer, it gives me an error.

> Windows cannot open the folder.
>
> The Compressed (zipped) Folder 'D:\TEST\VS\FilesAndFolders\TestDirectory\Archives\Zip-11-01-2015-04-18-58.zip' is invalid.

Perhaps, the code that I'm using is incomplete? or I missed something?

Comment: Correction to the last comment.

Comment: //zipFilePath = "D:\TEST\VS\FilesAndFolders\TestDirectory\Archives\Zip-11-01-2015-04-18-58.zip"

Comment: What library do you use for compression?

Comment: I think I was missing this. I added this just now after I posted the question. zipFile.Dispose(); After this when I ran the program, it created another new zip file which I can open using windows explorer. So looks like that dispose() method needs to be called before the program exists.

Comment: @Vnuuk - I'm using the following in my program.

Comment: using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO.Compression;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader;

Comment: Don't add code or corrections in comments, _edit_ and improve the question.

Comment: You seem to be missing a `.Close()` or indeed a `.Dispose()`

Comment: @Henk - That's what I spotted just after I posted. Now it seems to be working and I can open the zip file.

Comment: See my comment to `L. Tirnanic`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you have written a piece of code that opens the file and writes.
Once the process of creating the file and writing in it, you should tell the PC to close the file.

Im not exactly sure of the commands in this instance, try something like

```
zipFile.close;
```

Comment: or instead, a prettier and less error prone `using(ZipArchive zipFile = ZipFile.Open(zipFilePath, ZipArchiveMode.Create) { }`. by using the `using` tag and getting used to it, it lowers the risk of such bugs by removing the need to call dispose or close, because it is done at the end of the using block.